# Переносы строк в поле text

Tags: php

Как сделать переносы строк при выводе текста из таблицы, поле text? Данные закидываются через текстовую область, выводятся через nl2br. Но здесь показывается лишь 1 перенос, как сделать, чтобы показывал и 2 и 3 переноса?
Можно сделать типа

```
str_replace("
", "<br>", $text);
```

но этот вариант оказался нерабочим :(
Так же, в общем, при закидывание записи в бд, съедается 2 и более переноса, то есть остается лишь один. Можно ли это поправить?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать перенос с textarea в html надо:

```
<textarea>Текст. Дальше два переноса.

И снова текст </textarea>
```

В php попробуйте при операторе echo тоже сделать такое. Например:

```
echo "<textarea>Текст. Дальше два переноса.

И снова текст </textarea>";
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы не в текст. обл. выводился текст с переносом, т.к. там он выводится как нужно. Сейчас текст выводится с 1 тегом переноса из бд, через nl2br. Мне нужно, чтоб было 2-3 и более переносов, где нужно.

Comment: Странно, что nl2br() у вас съедает все переводы новой строки.

Попробуйте прибегнуть к регулярным выражениям и функции [preg_replace()][1].

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @rimlin Извините, что я вас не правильно понял.

Answer (score -1):

Если данные заносятся в базу данных, то в строке из текстового поля нужно экранировать пробельные символы (пробел, табуляция, перенос строки), что бы они не слиплись в один. Для MySQL это функция mysql_real_escape_string(), пример:

```
$mysql_result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table` (`text`) VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['textarea']).'")');
```

То есть переносы пропадают при вводе, а не при выводе.